# The method assertThat(HttpStatus, equalTo(HttpStatus.OK)) is undefined for the type ****Test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, http-headers

I am facing Issue , when i am try to test HTTP Status Code.

*The method assertThat(HttpStatus, equalTo(HttpStatus.OK)) is undefined for the type ExampleTest*

pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

What is messing in this code. Could anyone help me out.

**Thank you**

Comment: You are probably missing and import and need to show the code where this error actually occurs. Additionally, if you're using MockMvc, it's better to use `status().isOk()`, because you'll get better error reporting if it fails.

Comment: Thank you @chrylis-onstrike- , i will try to use MockMvc.